# Find index of error source in long sapply

Tags: r, debugging, sapply

I have an `sapply(X, function(blah blah blah)` function that is resulting in an error. The argument `X`, however is a vector with length > 1000. When I try a few of the values it works, but I know that at least one of the values in the vector `X` has an issue but I don't know which one. How can I figure out the index of the particular value that breaks the function? Can `sapply()` return the last iteration it completed before the error?

I know I can try the `X` vector in small chunks but I'm curious if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: You could add a `print(x)`-statement to your sapply-call. Then you'll know the first point it stops. Or wrap it into try/except.

Comment: For such debugging puposes, I would use a `for` loop instead of  `sapply` and print out the values and their indices to see where things start to go wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Heroka, your suggestion worked great! Feel free to add as an answer.